# Dealing with multi-column time series in TTR

Tags: r, time-series

I download 2 daily stock histories going back to 2000:

```
library(quantmod)
check <- c("FB","GOOG")
getSymbols(check, from='2000-01-01')
```

Isolate the last prices:

```
close <- cbind(Cl(GOOG),Cl(FB))
```

Now I would like to use some of the tools in the very nice 'TTR' package, for instance `SMA`:

```
smacheck <- SMA(close,50)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("GOOG.Close.SMA.50", "FB.Close.SMA.50":
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

`FB` has a shorter history than `GOOG`. How do I get this to work across both stocks, regardless of when the NA's start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the missing values.  `SMA` doesn't currently work on objects with more than one column.  You need to run `SMA` on each column individually.

```
library(quantmod)
e <- new.env()
getSymbols('GOOG;FB', from='2000-01-01', env=e)
smacheck <- do.call(merge, eapply(e, function(x) SMA(Cl(x), 50)))
```

Comment: Thank you- anyway that I can do this without creating a new .env?

Comment: @Rhodo: yes, but it involves more code. Something like: `sl <- list(); for(s in check) sl[[s]] <- SMA(Cl(get(s)),50); smacheck <- do.call(merge, sl)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `apply` function

```
SMAs <- xts(apply(close, MARGIN = 2, FUN = "SMA", n = 50), index(close))
head(SMAs)
##            GOOG.Close FB.Close
## 2004-08-19         NA       NA
## 2004-08-20         NA       NA
## 2004-08-23         NA       NA
## 2004-08-24         NA       NA
## 2004-08-25         NA       NA
## 2004-08-26         NA       NA

tail(SMAs)
##            GOOG.Close FB.Close
## 2013-10-29   899.6198  46.7544
## 2013-10-30   902.9198  46.9664
## 2013-10-31   906.1448  47.2042
## 2013-11-01   909.2114  47.4282
## 2013-11-04   912.3294  47.5816
## 2013-11-05   915.4320  47.7570
```